# How do I redirect certain paths with wildcards with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

For example I need to redirect urls that match this pattern and keep the rest.

```
aaa.mydomain.com/path/1/listing
```

to

```
bbb.somedomain.com/path/1/listing
```

The "1" in that path can be any integer and needs to go to the correct redirect. Can this be done with a location block or do i need rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
server {
  server_name aaa.mydomain.com;
  return 301 //bbb.somedomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

### UPDATE

Well, then use something like this

```
location ~ /path/[^/]+/listing$ {
  return 301 https://bbb.somedomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Oh no no. My bad. Didnt explain well. I just need to redirect this specific type of path. Not All paths.

Comment: Thanks that works. Unfortunately although the redirect works perfectly for GET and DELETE calls but POST calls fail with a BAD_REQUEST.

Comment: Well, then you can try with 308 and if it does not work (I am not sure at which version nginX started to support this status and also not all user agents understand this status code) then try with 307. They both preserve the HTTP method while 301 is usually understood by user agents as a permission to switch to GET.

Comment: Tried with 307 but still the same. I suspect its something to do with the Jetty/Jersey server thats behind nginx and not due to a config in nginx.

Comment: You should check the browser DevTools to confirm you get 307 and to confirm the browser does a 2nd POST and not a GET, then you should check the access/error logs of both Jetty and nginX. You already got the idea, not it is technical stuff and troubleshooting.

Comment: I know this is a very late update but I still use this snippet. I just use the location regex but with a proxy_pass directive to forward all requests.